# Which installation option I should use for SQL server 2008 to work with SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, sql-server

I want to prepare a development environment for SharePoint 2013, so I want to know which SQL server option I should use from the SQL server 2008 installation center , the available options are:-
1.New installation or add new feature
2.New failover.
3.Etc….

Can anyone advice which option I should use?

BR

Comment: First, you need 2008 R2 SP1, at minimum, 2008 wont work for you.  Tons of resources on deploying SQL server on the web for step by step deployment you can Simply bing or Google: "SQL Server Installation Step by step". Same for setting up a SharePoint 2013 Dev or Test installation. That being said.  Your installation option will depend on where and how you are deploying SQL Server. New Instance, New Cluster Node, etc,  There is not enough information to help you out.

Comment: yes I have SQL server 2008 R2 provided as ISO image...